# MySQL Stored Procedure Error #2014 - Commands out of sync

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have a fairly straight forward stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getBuyerID(
     IN personID INT(11),
     OUT buyerID INT(11)
)
BEGIN
SELECT BUYER_ID FROM BUYER WHERE PERSON_ID = personID;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The stored procedure went through without any errors. To test it I tried running a call to the stored procedure through phpMyAdmin with the following line.

```
CALL getBuyerID('28',@buyer_id); SELECT @buyer_id;
```

When I run the above line I get this error.

```
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

I noticed that I will get the result of the stored procedure in phpMyAdmin if I use only part of the call, like this.

```
CALL getBuyerID('28',@buyer_id);
```

But I'm at a loss as to why the original call is not working because that is how I've made calls before in the past. The call that's working is fine when testing in phpMyAdmin but I do not know how to retrieve the result that way when calling the stored procedure through PHP. Here is the code I've used in the past to call a stored procedure and get the result from within PHP.

```
$query  = "CALL getBuyerID('$person_id',@buyer_id)";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$query    = "SELECT @buyer_id as b";
$result   = mysql_query($query);
$row      = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$buyer_id = $row['b'];

echo "Buyer ID is $buyer_id";
```

Comment: you could just return the value from the procedure instead of shoving it in an out param. it may also be that phpmyadmin is using `mysql_*` calls, which apparently have issues with stored proceudres

Comment: What name would I use to retrieve the result in PHP? Or can I put "AS b" after the stored procedure query call?